# Call one function conditionally and one function every time the button is clicked in react JS

Tags: reactjs, buttonclick

I want to call function apiCall() every time the Cancel button is clicked and setSave() and setCreate() functions conditionally. Is there any way other than the wrapper function that I can use.
I am using Functional component and setSave and setCreate functions are useState functions and apiCall() is a function which I have received as a prop from parent function.

```
<input
              type="button"
              onClick={() => (id !== '' ? setSave(true) : setCreate(false))}
              value="Cancel"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
   <input
       type="button"
        onClick={() => {
         apiCall();
          if(id !== ''){
             setSave(true);
           }else{
             setCreate(false);
            }
          }
           value="Cancel"
    />
```